# Using Find Functions, Loops and Variable Worksheet Names

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I'm currently writing a bit of code that I am going to use to remove some pesky volatile 'indirect' functions in my xl workbook.

I have managed to write up as much code as I can but unfortunately I'm getting rather confused and need a bit of help to get me on the right track.

In the following list I have made a summary of what I'm trying to achieve with this code;

- The current active sheet is the "Input" sheet in this workbook.
- Loop through A2:A1000 in the Input "sheet" and if the value = "HT" then do the following;

  1. Set LeagueName = C(I)
  2. Set HomeTeam = D(I)
  3. Activate workbook "Users\Homes1\cs010ea\My Documents\Team Performance Factors.xlsx")
  4. Find the Sheet with the same name as the variable LeagueName
  5. Find the last occurring value equal to the HomeTeam variable in the column "C:C". Offset this to travel to the corresponding activerow cell in column K and copy that value.
  6. Return to the "Input" sheet in the previous workbook and pastespecial xlpastevalues in AO(I).

LOOP

I am aware this seems like a bit of a difficult task. I have done a lot of this code already I believe, however I am stuck on a few bits such as selecting a variable sheet name in another workbook! Here is my code;

```
    Sub TeamData()

    Dim i As Range
    Dim inputbook As Workbook
    Dim C As Range
    Dim HomeTeamRange As Range
    Dim HomeTeam As Range
    Dim HomeTeamValue As Range

    Set inputbook = ThisWorkbook
    Set TeamPerformance = Workbooks.Open("\\ad.nfumutual.co.uk\Users\Homes1\cs010ea\My Documents\WhoScored Scraping\Betting File\Team Performance Factors.xlsx")


    For Each i In Range("A2:A1000")
    If i.Value2 = "HT" Then
    Set LeagueName = Range("C" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    Set HomeTeam = Range("D" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    Workbooks("Users\Homes1\cs010ea\My Documents\Team Performance Factors.xlsx").Sheets(LeagueName).Select


    Set HomeTeamRange = Range("C:C")
    Set HomeTeamValue = HomeTeamRange.Find(what:=HomeTeam, after:=HomeTeamRange(1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Offset(0, 8).Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("AO" & (i)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

  End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: what error are you getting? And where does the error or unexpected behaviour happen (what line)?

Comment: also, no need to `Select` the workbook, you could just reference it as `With Workbooks("Users\Homes1\cs010ea\My Documents\Team Performance Factors.xlsx").Sheets(LeagueName)` **so long as it is open**

Comment: @ are you **sure** that this workbook *Users\Homes1\cs010ea\My Documents\Team Performance Factors.xlsx* has a worksheet called **LeageName**? Put a breakpoint on that line in the code (use F9) and run the macro then when it stops you can check the value in the Immediate Window (CTRL+G), with "`?LeagueName`"